# Change a UITableViewCell highlight color when selected (UITableViewCell is not in UITableView or a TableViewController)

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I have an individual `UITableViewCell` that is NOT inside a `UITableView` or `TableViewController`. I would like to change the `UITableViewCell` color when it is selected or touched. What is the best way to perform such a task? I tried using the table view cell selected delegate, but it did not work for me. Right now my `UITableViewCell` doesn't even change color when selected or touched. Any tips or suggestions will be appreciated.This is my `IBOutlet` for my `UITableViewCell`

**.h**

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableViewCell *cellLocation;
```

Comment: what do u mean, it is not inside a table view? a table view cell needs to be in a tableview. and what is the selection delegate? give us code!

Comment: Why are you using a UITableViewCell outside of a UITableView? Just create a custom UIView!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you try to understand how to use gui components provided by iOS first.

If you need a simple view then use a simple view instead of a `UITableViewCell` outside of a `UITableView`.